# OpenCV: Invert a mask?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a simple way to invert a mask using OpenCV? For example, if I've got a mask like this:

```
010
111
010
```

I'd like to invert it and get this:

```
101
000
101
```

Note: I'm using OpenCV's Python bindings, so while it would be *possible* to simply loop over each element in the mask, execution speed could become an issue.

Comment: Use a [bitwise Not](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html#not) to flip all bits in a matrix.

Comment: It's possible that I'm doing something stupid and wrong, but I don't think a bitwite-not is what I want… Because then I'll end up with `255,254,255,...`. Possibly it's because my mask is an `Image`?

Comment: It depends upon the bit depth of your mask. Normally a mask should have a depth of 1 bit, which would flip the single bit from 0 to 1 and vise versa. You might need to convert your mask to a 1 bit deep image first.

If you have a greater bit depth (ex 4), then yes it would flip from `0001` to `1110` and from `0000` to `1111`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have an 8-bit mask, then you should do `mask = 255 - mask`. cv::Mat subtraction operator is overloaded to do scalar per-element subtraction.

Answer (score 52):

`cv2.bitwise_not(mask)` would help here

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but it won't work for masks with different max_value, for example if one mask is 255 and zeros and the other is 1 and zeros, because it is a bit operator.

Comment: it not works for me, I see no changes

Answer (score 7):

For an 8 bit mask using 255 as "on" value:

```
mask = cv::Mat::ones(mask.size(), mask.type()) * 255 - mask;
```

I'm using this one instead of Matt M solution as I'm still using OpenCV 2.1.0 for one of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might handle the case where the input mask may have various non-zero values:

```
cv::Mat1b inputMask = ....;
cv::Mat1b invertedMask(inputMask.rows, inputMask.cols);

std::transform(
    inputMask.begin(), inputMask.end(), invertedMask.begin(),
    std::logical_not<uint8_t>()
);
```

Comment: it's not a c++ question