# How to remove a contoured area from an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask, feature-extraction

I have an **image with a white background** and some colored blocks. I have created multiple **filters to find the colored blocks** and get the contours for another purpose and I am able to draw the contours around the colored blocks.

These blocks are connected by some **black lines which I would like to get the contours of**. I was using the original contours to also get the lines but I was advised not to do that and instead remove the colored blocks from the image so that I would only remain with the black lines in the image making it easier to contour.

I have created a mask that would draw over the contoured block but when I display the **final image the contoured blocks are black** instead of white.

##### Is there any way to make the blocks white similar to the background so that I could remain with only the black lines?

[image: Source Image]

[image: Mask]

[image: Unwanted Result]

From the images, you can see that the mask covers the image and the black line remains. However, I can't figure out how to make the blocks white instead of black so that only the line remains.

```py
from ctypes import sizeof
from doctest import master
from cv2 import approxPolyDP, contourArea, cvtColor, inRange
import numpy as np 
import cv2

kernel = (5, 5)
srcImg = cv2.imread('BluePurpleConnected.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(srcImg, kernel, 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(srcImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rows = int(grayImg.shape[0]/2)
cols = int(grayImg.shape[1]/2)
ker = np.ones((0, 0), 'uint8')
graySize = grayImg.shape
sig = 0.33
cPix = 200
bPix = 255
lPurp = np.array([130, 20, 10])
uPurp = np.array([145, 255, 255])
lBlue = np.array([94, 80, 2])
uBlue = np.array([126, 255, 255])
colArray = np.array([lPurp, uPurp, lBlue, uBlue])
masterStruc = []
maskArray = []
mask = np.ones(srcImg.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
x = 0
while x <= 1:
    imgMask = cv2.inRange(hsv, colArray[2*x], colArray[2*x+1])
    maskArray.append(imgMask)
    v = np.median(imgMask)
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sig) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sig) * v))
    bwImg = cv2.Canny(imgMask, lower, upper)
    nbwImg = cv2.dilate(bwImg, kernel, iterations=1)
    cImg = nbwImg
    ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(cImg, cPix, bPix, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnt = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        curve = approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        vert = len(curve)
        area = cv2.contourArea(curve)
        if(area > 1000):
            if(vert == 4):
                masterStruc.append([x, curve, area])
                cv2.drawContours(mask, [curve], -1, 0, -1)
    x = x + 1
srcImg = cv2.bitwise_and(srcImg, srcImg, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('Image', srcImg)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please optimize your question details to be a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you might want to [Invert your mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261202/opencv-invert-a-mask)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'm new to the forum and not sure how to phrase my questions in the best way possible yet.

Comment: Invert using cv2.bitwise_not(mask) ? If so, I tried doing that and unfortunately it did not give the result I expected.

Comment: If I invert the mask using mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask) and then do srcImg = cv2.bitwise_and(srcImg, srcImg, mask = mask). I get the mask image being two white rectangles with a black background and the srcImg is a black background with the original rectangles (blocks)

Comment: using the mask that does not have  the line, do the following `srcimg[mask==0]=(255,255,255)`

Comment: @fmw42 Could you post your comment as the solution. That one singular line worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: nobody has mentioned morphology operations. you should try those.

Comment: Why is your input color image so much larger in dimensions than your mask image. Posting my solution is not possible since I do not know how your cropped your mask to the smaller size it has.